# How to enable json logs for aws msk

Tags: json, logging, apache-kafka, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-msk

I have created MSK cluster via CloudFormation and its logs are written to a log group . However, I run into the problem that the data is not formatted (see below). I would like to have the logs in JSON format to extract detailed metrics later using Logs Insights. Can someone please help me with this?

MSK-Cluster configuration in CloudFormation

```
  MSKCluster:
    Type: AWS::MSK::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: "MyMSKCluster"
      KafkaVersion: !Ref KafkaVersion
      NumberOfBrokerNodes: !Ref NumberOfBrokerNodes
      BrokerNodeGroupInfo:
        ClientSubnets:
          - "PrivateSubnetMSKOne"
          - "PrivateSubnetMSKTwo"
          - "PrivateSubnetMSKThree"
        InstanceType: !Ref BrokerNodeInstanceType
        SecurityGroups: [!GetAtt MSKSecurityGroup.GroupId]
        StorageInfo:
          EBSStorageInfo:
            VolumeSize: !Ref BrokerNodeEBSStorageVolumeSize
      ConfigurationInfo:
        Arn: !Ref MSKClusterConfiguration
        Revision: !Ref MSKClusterConfigurationRevision
      EnhancedMonitoring: PER_TOPIC_PER_BROKER
      OpenMonitoring:
        Prometheus:
          JmxExporter:
            EnabledInBroker: true
          NodeExporter:
            EnabledInBroker: true
      LoggingInfo:
        BrokerLogs:
          CloudWatchLogs:
            Enabled: true
            LogGroup: "MskClusterLogGroup"
          S3:
            Bucket: "MSKClusterLogsBucket"
            Enabled: true
```

some curent msk logs from cloudwatch

```
[2023-03-08 13:13:38,336] INFO Kafka version: 2.8.1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-03-08 13:13:38,336] INFO Kafka commitId: unknown (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-03-08 13:13:38,336] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1678281218335 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-03-08 13:13:38,337] INFO Kafka version: 2.8.1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-03-08 13:13:38,337] INFO Kafka commitId: unknown (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-03-08 13:13:38,337] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1678281218337 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-03-08 13:13:38,409] INFO App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-9608 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-03-08 13:13:38,412] INFO Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2023-03-08 13:13:38,412] INFO Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2023-03-08 13:13:38,412] INFO Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2023-03-08 13:13:38,412] INFO Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2023-03-08 13:13:38,412] INFO Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2023-03-08 13:13:38,412] INFO Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2023-03-08 13:13:38,413] INFO App info kafka.consumer for consumer-consumer-lag-9608 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-03-08 13:13:53,661] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to rebalance group amazon.msk.canary.group.broker-1 in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 19248 (__consumer_offsets-21) (reason: Adding new member consumer-amazon.msk.canary.group.broker-1-1111-asdffrr-wwer-43ttt37-8tt717-rerefef with group instance id None) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no configuration for this in the Kafka, alone. You'd need to override the log4j.properties file on the brokers to use a different logger LayoutPattern, or use a secondary tool like Filebeat, Fluentd, etc to parse lines into JSON.

That being said, the data is still "formatted". You've got a timestamp, followed by a log level, then the message, optionally starting with thread/MDC information, followed by a class name in parenthesis.

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/log4j.properties#L22